# scraping the each of the link pages and storing it as an XML table

Tags: r, css-selectors, rvest

Hello I'm new to using R to scrape data from the Internet and, sadly, know little about HTML and XML. Am trying to scrape each story link at the following parent page: https://news.google.com/search?q=NREGA&hl=en-IN&gl=IN&ceid=IN%3Aen I don't care about any of the other links on the parent page, but need to create a table with a columns for the URL, title of the story and then the rest for the complete text of the page (which can be several paragraphs of text).

I tried with the rvest package and got the urls but the real issue is getting over all the articles and extracting the text and storing all in a table.

### For Google News app:

```
library(rvest)

url <- 'https://news.google.com/search?q=NREGA&hl=en-IN&gl=IN&ceid=IN%3Aen'

webpage <- read_html(url)


data_html <- html_nodes(webpage, '.VDXfz') %>% html_att

r('href')
```

Answer (score -1):

I will provide the javascript examples since i am not aware of the library you are using.

1.Getting the links of all the urls :

```
var anchors = document.querySelectorAll("article  > a");
for(var i in anchors)
{
    console.log(anchors[i].getAttribute("href"));
}
```

2.Getting the headers of each url link :

```
 var headers = document.querySelectorAll("article  >  div:nth-of-type(1)");
 for(var i in headers)
 {
     console.log(headers[i].innerText);
 }
```

3.Getting the story once you navigated to that link :

```
var story = document.querySelector("div.full-details").innerText;
console.log(story);
```

This will fetch some extra details like number of shares on social media as visible on top, written by line , etc. If you want just the body without these details , you can get all paragraph elements using "**document.querySelectorAll("div.full-details p")**" and get **innerText** property for each of them which you can combine later.

Comment: thanks for the reply. but my specific requirement is to do it through R or Python. It could be through any package like rvest, XML, Rcrawler etc.....